# Get RowDefinition height programmatically

Tags: wpf

I have this XAML:

```
<Grid Background="LightYellow" Height="150" Width="150">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

And I'm trying to get the height of the second row like this:

```
height = grid.RowDefinitions[1].Height.Value;
```

But I get a 1. I tried ActualSize and it doesn't work either (returns 0). How can I get the height of the row?

Comment: When are you calling ActualHeight?  It looks like ActualHeight *should* work, but this will only be available once the grid has been measured and laid out.

Comment: @itowlson: You're right I'm calling it in the wrong place, the grid has not been drawn yet. I'm doing an object that draws itself based on its parent's size, I was calling the draw method when it's CellHeight / CellWidth dependency properties were modified. In the constructor it doesn't work because it already has a reference for the parent. Where would you recommend to get the width / height?

Comment: Your row is height \*, so the contained object will automatically be sized to fit the grid cell.  So have the contained object handle its own SizeChanged event, or override OnRenderSizeChanged.  Then you won't need to query the ActualHeight at all because you can get the size info from the event data, making your object independent of the container.

Comment: @itowlson: I used your method, but now I can't redraw it when the height changes, I have to trigger render by changing the size of the window. How can I simulate calling render again in a PropertyChangedCallBack method?

Comment: @itowlson: Btw, you should put the reply as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @itowlson: Nvm, I found the InvalidateVisual() method, it triggers the render again. Thanks! You should still post your reply as an answer to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the reason Height.Value returns 1 is that Height is a GridLength, with a GridUnitType of Star.  The 1 is from proportional star sizing (e.g. Height="2*", Height="3*", etc.).  I.e. you can't read GridLength.Value in isolation: you *have* to read it in conjunction with the GridUnitType.

Now to the real issue.  WPF does not calculate the ActualHeight of elements until they are measured, which it does as part of the display pass.  From the [RowDefinition.ActualHeight docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.actualheight.aspx):

> When you add or remove rows or
>   columns, the ActualWidth for all
>   ColumnDefinition elements and the
>   ActualHeight of all RowDefinition
>   elements becomes zero until Measure is
>   called.

So if you try to get ActualHeight before WPF has called Measure, you'll get 0 or some other bad result.

Fortunately, you don't actually *need* to get ActualHeight: because WPF is going to size your object to the available space (because of star sizing), you can actually have the object handle its own SizeChanged event or override OnRenderSizeChanged.  Depending on how your rendering works, this event handler might update the object's set of child objects (if the object is a panel- or drawing-type object) or force a re-render using InvalidateVisual (if the object draws in a more immediate-mode style e.g. by overriding OnRender).

Comment: Using OnRender without OnRenderSizeChanged worked in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

You might want to consider inheriting from the grid and overriding the measure and arrange methods, if you are trying to change the default layout.

Comment: It's not that, I'm trying to make a control that draws itself based on the size of its parent. If it's a StackPanel it's pretty straight forward, but if it's a grid, I have to consider the height of the row that contains it and the width of the column.